# GCM not registering device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

hi all i have searched google and looked on all links on stacj overflow but none of them are working for me.

i am running the application on my samsung galaxy s3 through eclipse
it tries for 5 attempts and then fails to register

here is my common utilities:
{package com.example.driver;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public final class CommonUtilities {

```
// give your server registration url here
static final String SERVER_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/gcm_server_php/register.php"; 

// Google project id
static final String SENDER_ID = "14xxxxxxxxx9"; 

/**
 * Tag used on log messages.
 */
static final String TAG = "AndroidHive GCM";

static final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION =
        "com.androidhive.pushnotifications.DISPLAY_MESSAGE";

static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";

/**
 * Notifies UI to display a message.
 * <p>
 * This method is defined in the common helper because it's used both by
 * the UI and the background service.
 *
 * @param context application's context.
 * @param message message to be displayed.
 */
static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

}

}

and my register.php:

```
<?php

// response json
$json = array();

/**
 * Registering a user device
 * Store reg id in users table
 */
if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["regId"])) {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $gcm_regid = $_POST["regId"]; // GCM Registration ID
    // Store user details in db
    include_once './db_functions.php';
    include_once './GCM.php';

    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $gcm = new GCM();

    $res = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $gcm_regid);

    $registatoin_ids = array($gcm_regid);
    $message = array("product" => "shirt");

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

    echo $result;
} else {
    // user details missing
}
?>
```

any help will be highly appreciated
thanks

Comment: the tutorial i used is: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Any error messages on logcat? Anyhow, you should make sure you have the correct permissions for your device, and there are also a few steps to set up the client side before registering and being able to receive messages; you should read the official docs, see if you have accidentally missed something :) [**Link**](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)

Comment: at first i wasn't getting any error but now i am getting this error: java exception: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 port 8080
i have followed every step and have all the permissions

Comment: it returns: 
java.io.ioexception post failed with error code 404